# Check successive excel records and if they are the same, assign them identical ID's

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, data-manipulation

I have a large excel file with the following format:

```
Contact First Name  Contact Last Name   Contact ID
       Brandi             Aasen          1602940
       Brandi             Aasen          1600622
       Brandi             Aasen          1600622
       Angela             Abate          1600846
       Angela             Abate          1600846
       Edahena            Lucido         1603494
       Guadalupe          Delgado        1602523
       Guadalupe          Delgado        1602087
       Tonya              Addams         1602339
```

What I am needing is to adjust it so that if the contact name is the same, the contact ID must be the same as well. As of now, every single ID in the file is different. It doesn't even matter if I use any of the actual ID's listed there in the file. For instance, Brandi Aasen is just fine with the ID "0001", so long as "0001" is the ID set for all three instances of her. The file is sorted by Last Name then first name, so all of the duplicate contacts follow each other one after another.

I'm having a hard time finding an efficient way to do this. Admittedly I don't have much experience with excel. If I try something simple like:

```
=IF((AND(F2=F3,G2=G3)),(H2),(H3))
```

I run into trouble immediately, because series continues as I move down the column and the conditional cell numbers get all out of sorts.

What I was thinking is that I might be better off if I combine columns A and B into one. If I have the full name in a single column, is there anyway I could implement something like (pseudocode):

```
For all instances of A2 -> Set the adjacent column cell(B) to an arbitrary value
```

OR

```
If A2 = A3 -> B3 = B2
```

The original simple formula I posted at the beginning would almost work if it could go something like:

```
=IF((AND(F2=F2,G3=G3)),(H3=H2),(H3))
```

But excel doesn't seem to allow for me to use the "H3=H2" statement as the "Value if True"

Truly appreciate any help or guidance in the right direction.

Comment: `=IF((AND(F2=F2,G3=G3)),H2, H3) ` always return H2 (`F2` is always equal to `F2`, the same `F3`). Is it a typo? Could you correct?

Comment: Is the column "Contact ID" necessary for something? You say ` Brandi Aasen is just fine with the ID "0001"`, does it mean you want to add a new column or update the "Contact ID"?

Comment: @Voitcus Yes it was a typo - sorry about that - fixed it. I only included the contact ID for intuition - the number you see in the contact ID field "1602940"  is not necessary for anything. I probably should have just left it out - I am guessing it's going to be easiest to just add a new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is perfect solution, however I would do something like this:

I consider that First Name is in `A` column and Last Name is in `B` column. The ID you want to insert will be in the `D` column. The header is in `1`st row, so Brandi, Aasen is in `2`nd row.

In `D2` you just type `1`, as this is the first index.

In `D3` type `=IF(AND(A3=A2;B3=B2);D2;D2+1)`. Copy formula to all other `D` cells.

The function checks if the active pair (`A3`, `B3`) is the same as previous one (`A2`, `B2`). If `true`, the same number is taken (from `D2`). If not, the number is taken from above and increased.

Comment: Simple and effective - This is what I was looking for - I was getting bogged down by syntax. I really appreciate the help. I did have to modify it a bit - I am using excel 2011 for OS X, it wasn't having the semicolons. The final formula looks like this: =IF((AND(F3=F2,G3=G2)),(I2),(I2+1)  ... I have some other data in the first 5 columns of my file so the column letters are switched. Thank you very much !

Comment: You are welcome. Please note, this would only work if data is sorted. If not, more complex functions should be used, eg. `VLOOKUP`

Comment: Indeed -- The data is sorted.